# Indexing a table by asset symbol -- how to find?

Tags: table, eosio.cdt

suppose I declare:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] tst {
   asset component;
   uint64_t primary_key() const {
      return component.symbol.code().raw();
   }   
};
```

where I mean to keep a list of assets.  when it's time to find a record in the table I want to do something like:

```
void token::find(char *symbol) {
   tst t(_self, _self.value);
   auto o = t.find(symbol);
```

but this results in an error:

> t.cpp:127:20: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'uint64_t'
>   (aka
>         'unsigned long long') with an lvalue of type 'char *'
>                           auto o = t.find(symbol);

changing the parameter definition to:

```
void token::find(std::string symbol) {
```

produces a similar message:

> t.cpp:127:20: error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka
>         'basic_string, allocator >') to 'uint64_t'
>         (aka 'unsigned long long')
>                           auto o = t.find(symbol);

in other code I've seen these finds done given an asset.  something like this works:

```
auto o = t.find(someAsset.symbol.code().raw());
```

which ultimately resolves to a `uint64_t`

**so I need somehow to convert my string to an integer.  can anyone provide a hint as to how I might do this?**

Answer (score 1):

When you are lost with EOSIO native types, you can look it up at eosio.cdt's eosiolib library ([github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/tree/master/libraries/eosiolib))

A explicit constructor is defined as following inside `symbol.hpp`

```
constexpr explicit symbol_code( std::string_view str )
      :value(0)
      {
         if( str.size() > 7 ) {
            eosio::check( false, "string is too long to be a valid symbol_code" );
         }
         for( auto itr = str.rbegin(); itr != str.rend(); ++itr ) {
            if( *itr < 'A' || *itr > 'Z') {
               eosio::check( false, "only uppercase letters allowed in symbol_code string" );
            }
            value <<= 8;
            value |= *itr;
         }
      }
```

`symbol.hpp` is included in `asset.hpp` so it should be fine to include just the`eosiolib/asset.hpp` as usual.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I guess the answer is I can do something like `symbol::symbol_code("USD")`.  I've marked your reply as the answer even though it doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: actually, the above doesn't work.  so I'll reopen this question